How do I remove this motorcycle indicator bulb?
I am trying to remove this indicator bulb from a 2012 Kawasaki W800. I've try twisting to unscrew and pushing it in like a bayonet but it's not budging. I even tried some needle-nose pliers around the base to try and turn it but no good.
Anyone have any ides how to remove it?


Have you tried to lub it? Is it possible that the mechanism is a push + 1/4 turn system.

It could be that the solder contacts on the bulb have been impressioned by the pins in the base so it's extra difficult to twist. Can you remove the bulb holder to gain access to that area? Assume that the glass will get broken in the process of removing the bulb and wear suitable hand and eye protection.

As @5n10m stated in comments, you have to push it down (probably about 1/4"), then twist it counterclockwise about a 1/4 turn (if that). There are two pins on the bulb which latch it in place. Considering this is a single filament bulb, the pins will be on the same level. If the bulb is dead already, I wouldn't worry too much about destroying this bulb to get it out.
You'll need to use some penetrant around the base and get the original bulb to move up and down, then you can probably twist it. Once out, you'll want to clean the socket very well to help it not do this again.
